# Dell Precision 5520 - 2 monitors, one is fine the other's resolution is messed up

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I just got a new Dell Precision 5520 laptop along with the Dell "cube" docking station. I have two monitors attached - one a ViewSonic and the other a Samsung. The Viewsonic looks great but the Samsung's resolution is off. Everything is too big. The're both set to 1280x1024, although the Samsung has other options (1360x768, 1366x768, 1400x1050, 1440x900 1600x900, 1680x1050 and 1920x1080). If I choose a higher resolution the Samsung just goes dark. Under device drivers I show 2: an Intel HD Graphics 630 and an NVIDIA Quadro M1200.

I should add that the Samsung is currently connected using a VGA cable. The docking station has one HDMI out, one VGA out and one Display Port out. The Samsung monitor has one VGA in and one DVI in. The ViewSonic is connected to the the HDMI port.

How can I get better resolution on the Samsung?

Comment: Model numbers for the monitors would be helpful. 1280x1024 is a 4:3 aspect (or close), and the Samsung sounds like it is 16:9

Comment: It sounds like the monitors are set up as duplicate images, which would force the resolution to be the same (lowest common denominator).  You may need to set it up as extended so they are independent, then set each one to display the same thing (at its native resolution).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by buying a cable that converts from DVI to Display Port. Works fine now.

Thanks for the advice.